# How to call object method when `this` doesnt reference the object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

I'm relatively new to the latest and greatest of Javascript (as a holdover from my IE6 days) and I dont fully understand the syntax. I am writing a Wordpress theme using Sage's Roots. The way they set up the JS is that each page gets a boilerplate JS file

**home.js**

```
export default {
  init() {
  },
  finalize() {

  },
}
```

Where `init` is called on page load and `finalize` on unload. I'm trying to break up my init into functions but I cant figure out the scoping issues.

```
export default {
  init() {
    let trigger = document.body;
    trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // how do i call 'something'?
    });
  },
  finalize() {

  },
  something() {
      console.log('something happened');
  }
}
```

Normally, I might create a variable in a higher scope and save `this` upon init, e.g., `var klass = this` and reference it using `klass.something()` but I cant figure out where to even put that line.

How do I reference the `something` method when `this` has been overwritten in a different scope?

EDIT: Also noteworthy: I want to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: `=>` functions do not get their own `this`; they use the `this` from the lexical scope in which they're declared, so in your case it'd be `this.something()`

Comment: Thanks! I see that works. Though, you exposed a problem with my question. I copied the wrong syntax from my file and I was originally getting the error with an inline function before I changed to the `=>`. Since this sidesteps my original issue, I am going to edit my question to contain the original syntax that I was having an issue with. Switching to `=>` seems like it could be a good answer for that question!

Comment: Keep in mind that due to it being a ES6 module, any code used is not global. So you are not forced to only work inside the returned object. You can ( probably, haven't used WP the last couple of years ) do stuff like: `class MyThing { constructor(){} init(){} finalize() }; const instance = new MyThing(); export default instance;`. You are only bound to exporting a default object with the `init()` and `finalize()` functions/methods.

Comment: Thanks Shilly. I (obviously) didnt know that. You correctly identified an unspoken assumption I had made - that anything outside that export statement would be global.

Comment: @Shilly There's no reason to use a `class` though if you plan to instantiate it only once. OP is using plain object literals, which is much better.

Comment: I was just giving an example that you aren't forced to work inside the exported template they gave the OP. If you only need a singleton, a literal is indeed easier to use. But I didn't think that would matter. On another day I'd have wrote an example like: `const a = 'some_value'; const b = 42; export default { a, b, init: () => {}, finalize: () => {} }` to signify that `a` and `b` don't become global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're exporting an object, you can an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow functions don't define their own `this` and so you can use the `this` of the object.

```
export default {
  init: () => {
    let trigger = document.body;
    trigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.something();
    });
  },
  finalize: () => {},
  something: () => {
    console.log("something happened");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function in Javascript are lexically scoped, they define `'this'` based on where they are written.
Instead going for arrow function go with regular function declaration which is `'dynamically scoped'` and here you will be able to call `'something()'` using `'this'`

Change you code like below -

```
export default {
init() {
    let trigger = document.body;
    trigger.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.something();
    });
},
finalize() {

},
something() {
    console.log('something happened');
  }
}
```